# Graph how to get all indirect successors of a graph?

Tags: python, networkx

I wish to make the following list into a networkx graph

```
testlist = [(0, 1), (0, 5), (1, 2), (2, 9), (5, 3),(6, 4), (4, 9)]
```

and get all the indirect out successors like this:

```
# all_edges = [(0, 1), (0, 5), 
#              (1, 2), (0, 2),
#              (1, 9), (2, 9),
#              (5, 3), (0, 3), 
#              (6, 4), (4, 9), 
#              (6, 9)]
```

I have read the tutorial and couldn't find a way to do it.

I think it might be a direct graph with successors()?
Any hints would be appreciated.

Attempt:

```
list1 = [sum(nx.dfs_successors(L, i).values(), []) for i in L.nodes()]   

list2 = [i for i in L.nodes()]
```

then the cartesian product of list2 and list1

```
import itertools
list3 = [j for i in range(len(list1)) for j in itertools.product([list2[i]],list1[i]) ]
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1),
 (0, 5),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 9),
 (0, 3),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 9),
 (5, 3),
 (2, 9),
 (6, 4),
 (6, 9),
 (4, 9)]
```

I figured it out. But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please edit the title: `Hraph` -> `Graph`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools
import networkx as nx

#Make the list into a directed graph
L = nx.DiGraph(testlist)

#Here this list comprehension will get successors from all layers

list1 = [sum(nx.dfs_successors(L, i).values(), []) for i in L.nodes()]   

#All the nodes
list2 = [i for i in L.nodes()]

#cartesian product(cross product) within the lists of lists. This will 
#create all the (node, successor)

list3 = [j for i in range(len(list1)) for j in itertools.product([list2[i]],list1[i]) ]
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: Thanks. I just added some comments.